# python curve_fitting with bad results

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

[the link of data from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cciw4h7yrmc1qx/data.rar?dl=0)[badfitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODiax.png)I tried use the curve_fit to fit the data with my **pre_defined** function in python, but the result was far to perfect. The code is simple and shown as below. I have no idea what's wrong. 

Since I am new to python, are there any other optimization or fitting methods which are suitable for my case with predefined function?

Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, r1, r2, r3,l,c):
    w=2*math.pi*x
    m=r1+(r2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)+r3/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
    n=(r2**2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)-r3**3*c*w/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
    y= (m**2+n**2)**.5
    return y

def readdata(filename):
    x = filename.readlines()
    x = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), x))
    x = list(map(float, x))
    return x

 # test data
f_x= open(r'C:\Users\adm\Desktop\simpletry\fre.txt')
xdata = readdata(f_x)

f_y= open(r'C:\Users\adm\Desktop\simpletry\impedance.txt')
ydata = readdata(f_y)

xdata = np.array(xdata)
ydata = np.array(ydata)
plt.semilogx(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds=((0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)))
plt.semilogx(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label='fitted curve') 

print(popt)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

as you guessed, this is a LCR circuit model. now I am trying to fit two curves with the same parameters like

```
def func1(x, r1, r2, r3,l,c):
w=2*math.pi*x
m=r1+(r2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)+r3/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
return m

def func2(x, r1, r2, r3,l,c):
w=2*math.pi*x
n=(r2**2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)-r3**3*c*w/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
return n
```

is it possible to use the curve_fitting to optimize the parameters?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data files?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cciw4h7yrmc1qx/data.rar?dl=0

Comment: Do you have any idea what the approximate right answer is? You can use that to specify a starting point and bounds that might help the curve-fit routine.

Comment: It looks like the best fit has *negative* values for some of the parameters, so you should just remove the `bounds=...` part of the call. (Also, I suspect that there may be some degeneracy in your fit -- i.e., more than one set of parameters fits the data just as well.)

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. I had tried to remove the bounds and it can fit well. but the fact is that ALL the parameters need to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my results using scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to generate the initial parameter estimates for curve_fit, along with a simple "brick wall" in the function to ensure all parameters are positive. Scipy's implementation of Differential Evolution uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, which requires bounds within which to search - in this example, those bounds are taken from the data maximum and minimum values. My results:

RMSE: 7.415

R-squared: 0.999995

r1 = 1.16614005e+00

r2 = 2.00000664e+05

r3 = 1.54718886e+01

l = 1.94473531e+04

c = 4.32515535e+05

[image: semilog output]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

def func(x, r1, r2, r3,l,c):
    # "brick wall" ensuring all parameters are positive
    if r1 < 0.0 or r2 < 0.0 or r3 < 0.0 or l < 0.0 or c < 0.0:
        return 1.0E10 # large value gives large error, curve_fit hits a brick wall

    w=2*numpy.pi*x
    m=r1+(r2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)+r3/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
    n=(r2**2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)-r3**3*c*w/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
    y= (m**2+n**2)**.5
    return y


def readdata(filename):
    x = filename.readlines()
    x = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), x))
    x = list(map(float, x))
    return x

 # test data
f_x= open('/home/zunzun/temp/data/fre.txt')
xData = readdata(f_x)

f_y= open('/home/zunzun/temp/data/impedance.txt')
yData = readdata(f_y)

xData = numpy.array(xData)
yData = numpy.array(yData)


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)
    minBound = min(minX, minY)
    maxBound = max(maxX, maxY)
    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minBound, maxBound]) # search bounds for r1
    parameterBounds.append([minBound, maxBound]) # search bounds for r2
    parameterBounds.append([minBound, maxBound]) # search bounds for r3
    parameterBounds.append([minBound, maxBound]) # search bounds for l
    parameterBounds.append([minBound, maxBound]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    plt.semilogx(xData, yData, 'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    yModel = func(xData, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    plt.semilogx(xData, yModel) 

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: thanks for your code. 
now I am trying to fit two curves with the same parameters like

`**def func1(x, r1, r2, r3,l,c):**
w=2*math.pi*x
m=r1+(r2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)+r3/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
return m

**def func2(x, r1, r2, r3,l,c):**
w=2*math.pi*x
n=(r2**2*l*w)/(r2**2+l**2*w**2)-r3**3*c*w/(1+r3*c**2*w**2)
return n`

is it possible to use the curve_fitting to optimize the parameters?

Comment: Looks to me as if you can simply replace the fitted function in my example with the code in your comment. Note that I used "numpy.pi" as I did not "import math" in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

To have your Least Squares regression make sense, you'll have to at least supply initial parameters which make sense.

As all parameters are by default initiated to the value 1, the biggest influence on the initial regression will be resistor `r1` which adds a constant to the mix.

Most probably you'll end up in something like the following configuration:

```
popt
Out[241]: 
array([1.66581563e+03, 2.43663552e+02, 1.13019744e+00, 1.20233767e+00,
       5.04984535e-04])
```

Which will output a neat-looking flat line, due to `m = something big + ~0 + ~0` ; `n=~0 - ~0`, so `y = r1`.

However, if you initialize your parameters somewhat differently,

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata.flatten(), ydata.flatten(), p0=[0.1,1e5,1000,1000,0.2],
    bounds=((0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf)))
```

You will get a better looking fit,

```
popt
Out[244]: 
array([1.14947146e+00, 4.12512324e+05, 1.36182466e+02, 8.29771756e+04,
       1.77593448e+03])

((fitted-ydata.flatten())**2).mean()
Out[257]: 0.6099524982664816
#RMSE hence 0.78
```

[image]

P.s. My data starts at the second data point, due to a conversion error with `pd.read_clipboard` where the first row became headers instead of data. Shouldn't change the overall picture though.

Comment: How did you determine these initial parameter estimates?

Comment: By figuring out it was a RLC circuit-like; roughly figuring C to be smaller than 1, R to be on the order of thousands; from the final part of the curve noting that R1 should be small. Manual labour in this case, I'm afraid @JamesPhillips . And then being wrong about my assumption on C, according to the fit.. :(

Comment: I will spend a week writing code to avoid 10 minutes of manual labor...

Comment: I am afraid I would not like to spend my time on writing code which effectively brute-forces an optimal parameter initialization, whereas just picking some numbers; preferably non-uniform; will do the trick. Maybe if I need to reproduce similar thousands of times, but not for a single instance. ;)

Comment: The genetic algorithm in scipy allows a more general solution with wide applicability to many problems - hence my answer.

Comment: I agree it is copy-pastable to other places. But I am wary of complicated solutions generating RMSE a full order of magnitude worse than the simple one.

Comment: @Uvar, yeah, it's a RLC similar circuit.   thanks, it really help a lot.

Comment: @JamesPhillips. As you show, using DE to randomly explore starting points *can* work.  Still, using any prior knowledge one has about a problem is very important and should be used.  As you say,  DE requires user-supplied bounds on the randomly searched parameter values. That is, even if you do not give a set of initial values, you do have to give a *range* of values.  You chose these *from the range of data values*.  Why?  You keep asking folks to justify starting values.  What is your justification for that approach? It turns out they weren't bad, but far from perfect.

Comment: I will carefully consider what you have written.